# replace default browser confirm with jQuery fancy box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Instead of basic browser confirm box, I would like to replace it with fancy box.

My default confirm work as below:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><a class="btn-remove" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?');" title="Remove This Item" href="http://google.com">Default</a></p>
```

I tried to replace it as below,

```
<p><a class="btn-remove" onclick="return getConfirm();" title="Remove This Item" href="http://google.com">Test</a></p>

<script type="text/javascript">

        function getConfirm(){
            jQuery.fancybox("#data");
            $('#yes').on('click', function(){
                console.log('I am clicked');
                return true;
            })
            $('#no').on('click', function(){
                return false;
            })
            return false;
        }
</script>
```

```js
function getConfirm(){
   jQuery.fancybox("#data");
   $('#yes').on('click', function(){
    console.log('I am clicked');
    return true;
   })
   $('#no').on('click', function(){
    return false;
   })
   return false;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>

<p><a class="btn-remove" onclick="return getConfirm();" title="Remove This Item" href="http://google.com">Test</a></p>
<div id="data" style="display:none">
 <p>Are you sure want to colse?</p>
 <p><div id="yes">Yes</div><div id="no">No</div></p>
</div>
```

But it is not returning true to href and hence page is not redirecting.

Comment: have you ever used [sweet alert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)? I find it works great as an alert/confirm modal.

Comment: @BobNocraz its looking nice will check further and implement cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning `true` from the click handler only, not the `getConfirm` function.

As clicking the `#yes` button happens later (async), it's just too late to return anything to the anchor, that ship has sailed, and now you have to redirect yourself, as the fancybox dialog doesn't halt the browser UI and wait for a response in the same way a native confirm does.

```
function getConfirm(anchor){

    jQuery.fancybox("#data");

    $('#yes').on('click', function(){
        window.location.href = anchor.href;
    });

    $('#no').on('click', function(){
        // close fancybox
        return false;
    });

    return false;
}
```

and make sure you pass `this`

```
<a class="btn-remove" onclick="return getConfirm(this);" ...
```

Comment: if this is the case any other way to apply styles for browsers default alert box ?

Comment: Nope, generally the native confirm dialog isn't styleable, but using something like fancybox should work just fine, you just have to do a little more work yourself, redirecting, returning etc.